# executeAsyncScript timing out

Tags: rest, xmlhttprequest, protractor

I am trying to execute `executeAsyncScript` using the following code:

```
function get(url) {
  var callback = function(args) {
    console.log(args);
  };

  var defer = protractor.promise.defer();
  browser.executeAsyncScript(function (url, callback) {
    console.log("url" + url);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        callback(xhr.responseText);
        defer.fulfill(xhr);
      }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', url , true);
    xhr.send();
  }, url);

  return defer.promise;
};

function setupCommon() {
  return get('https://example.com/rest/api/getsomething');
}

var flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow();
flow.execute(setupCommon);
```

If I execute the code that is passed to executeAsyncScript directly in the browser console then it works. I get the expected output.

```
console.log("url" + url);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    callback(xhr.responseText);
    defer.fulfill(xhr);
  }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'https://example.com/rest/api/getsomething', true);
xhr.send();
```

But when I execute it using executeAsyncScript, it times out saying:

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

The restapi shouldn't have taken much time. I am new to all this. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The default timeout for Jasmine is 2000 milli-seconds which looks inadequate in your case as it looks like you indeed have lot of steps

Check the config file reference [doc here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L524) for different timeout configurations from the `protractor.conf.js`

You can either increase the timeout at config level as in below

`defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,
allScriptsTimeout:90000`

Or increase it for this test case alone

`this.timeout(60000)`

Answer (score 0):

The default timeout for a script to be executed is 0ms. In most cases, including the examples below, one must set the script timeout WebDriver.Timeouts.setScriptTimeout(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) beforehand to a value sufficiently large enough.

Here is link for Java API that provides above information

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeAsyncScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-